# Data format - JSON

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

I have a JSON output from a non-configurable system where various date/time variables have values like \/Date(1422691756316)\/ 
How can I get that into a readable format (I need to display it via PHP and Javascripts).

Answer (score 0):

You could deserialize the JSON output via `json_decode()` and then you could try to parse the string to an timestamp with `strtotime` (http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php), then you could create a date from thins timestamp using the `date()` method (http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) with a given formatting string an the timestamp.

But I'm not sure if your date string is ready to be parsed. In all cases you may to remove the `\/Date(` and `)\/` parts of the string.

**EDIT**: Looks like your string is not a timestamp, `strtotime` fails. You may have to check what kind of timestamp/ datestamp/ whatever your string is.

Comment: Thanks - I expect the value is to be like this "29-11-2014 16:47:55" and is a time/data stamp for a change. I will start stripping the string for start end end characters

Comment: Do you know what kind of format is behind your date string?

Comment: Its hard to say if the value itself is different depending on what language/region setting the systtem uses, or if it just changes in the gui. But the guy show them as dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: It seems to be a kind of timestamp. But until you don't know which content you get with this timestamp, you may can not continue.

Comment: I got it with : var reformatted = new Date(parseInt(reformatted.substr(6)));

Comment: I'm a little bit confused - do you need to work with it in js oder php?

Comment: It is in a javascript where I recieve the data, so I need to reformat it before updating div's in the php